# How to remove <img> tags with no src in a each loop

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to remove from the DOM any  element from my #owl-demo div that contains a null src (no image) .. heres what i tried, but no success..

```
$j("#owl-demo img").each(function(i, img) {        
      if(img.src == "")
          img.remove();
 });
```

Comment: Is it in a DOM ready handler?

Comment: Does the img elements have an attribute src?

Comment: Posting the HTML might be helpful.

Comment: yes, the img elements have an attribute src.. but the value is a empty string .. double quotes "" ..

Heres the HTML .. btw, im setting the src image via jquery .. but the number of images doesnt match the number of img tags .. so i need to exclude the img tags left with no src image

<pre>
<div data-role="content" class="jqm-content">
                <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
                    
                    <img src="">
                    <img src="">
                    <img src="">
                    <img src="">
                   
</pre>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming $j() is jQuery, this removes all `<img>` tags with no `src` attribute:

```
$j('#owl-demo img:not([src])').remove();
```

if you want to also remove images with an empty `src` attribute:

```
$j('#owl-demo img:not([src]), #owl-demo img[src=""]').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G2yX2/

edit: you can also simplify this by filtering instead of combining selectors:

```
$j('#owl-demo img').filter(':not([src]), [src=""]').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your images have no `src` property whatsoever, you can simply select:

```
$('#owl-demo img').not('[src]').remove();
```

Otherwise you can check to see whether the `src` property is undefined using `typeof`:

```
$("#owl-demo img").each(function() {        
    if(typeof this.src === 'undefined')
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Just make $('#owl-demo img').not('[src]').remove();

Comment: @joseeight oops, I forgot that `#owl-demo` part. :)

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO as it looks at the faster browser assisted method to removed images via querySelector and then fallback to JavaScript for the rest. I'm assuming you run both.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $j("#owl-demo img").each(function(i, img) {        
         if( $(img).attr('src') === "" )
             $(img).remove();
      });
```

Comment: `img.src` in OP's code is valid. There's no need to expensively call `attr()` here.